# how to estimate the eigenvalue of a covariance matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

if $x_i\in\mathbb R^n$ and $\max_i\|x_i\|_2\le 1$
$$A=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_ix_i^T$$

$\lambda$ is a eigenvalue of $A$, how to prove $\lambda\in[0,1]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, show that for any $x$ with $\|x\| \leq 1$, we have $\|xx^T\| \leq 1$.

Then, if $A_i = x_ix_i^T$, it suffices to note by the triangle inequality and homogeneity of a norm that
$$
\left\| \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n A_i \right\| \leq
\frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n \|A_i\|
$$